# How do I look up a value in a 2-D table in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Given a two-dimensional table with row and column headers, like this:

[image]

What is the formula to return the value at the intersection of a particular row and column? For example, I want a formula that would take "Blue" and 180 and return $2.20 in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=INDEX($C$4:$E$9,MATCH(180,$B$4:$B$9,0),MATCH("Blue",$C$3:$E$3,0))
```

returns $2.20.

Comment: Thanks! By naming the column headers "ColHeaders", the row headers "RowHeaders", and the data area "Data", I was able to write this as =INDEX(Data,MATCH(180,RowHeaders,0),MATCH("Blue",ColHeaders,0))

Comment: Important to remember the non-optional third argument to MATCH which must be 0 for an exact match

Comment: @Joel Spolsky: You're more than welcome.